# Why are nested FileType autocommands triggered even ++nested is not used?

Tags: autocmd, filetype

From `:h autocmd-nested`, it says "By default, autocommands do not nest." But nested FileType events are triggered anyway without using `++nested`. As seen in this test:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead tst setlocal filetype=tst | let b:tst = 1
autocmd FileType tst let b:tst = 2 | let b:filetype_event_triggered = 'true'
```

Running `e tst | echo b:tst` prints `1`, showing that the FileType autocommand is run before `let b:tst = 1`.

So is FileType event supposed to always run nested despite what the manual says, or am I missing something?

(Using vim 8.1)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, setting some options in Vim may have various side effects (see [source code](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/47c5ea44b975adca00eaacecee5c4108996178d9/src/optionstr.c#L2341)). In particular, setting `&filetype` and `&syntax` triggers the corresponding autocommands, even if invoked from inside another autocommand and no nested attribute is provided.

I'm not sure if it's documented anywhere, but standard Vim scripts, such as `filetype.vim` etc., heavily rely on this and never ever say "nested" either.